# Boundedness of multiplication operator on $L^p$ spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I am asking myself when a $L^p\to L^q$ multiplication operator is continuous. The following should be true:

Let $a:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ be a measurable function.  Let $T_a: L^p([0,1])\to L^q([0,1])$, with $p,q\in[1,\infty]$, $p<q$,  be the operator of pointwise multiplication  by $a$, i.e., $(T_af)(x):=a(x)f(x)$. Then $T_a$ is continuous if and only if $a=0$ (almost everywhere).

Any suggestion for a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 5):

If $a(x)$ is not the zero function, there is an $\epsilon > 0$ and a set $E$ of positive measure such that $|a(x)| > \epsilon$ on $E$. Use characteristic functions of subsets of $E$ to show that there cannot be such boundedness.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand that one has to "pile up" a number of characteristic functions supported in $E$, and to set their magnitude so that they are $p$-summable but not $q$-summable, but at the moment I cannot figure out their exact shape.

Comment: All you have to show is that the $L^p$ to $L^q$ norm is not bounded by any $C$... so if you can show that given $C$ you can always find a characteristic function which violates that $C$ then you are done. Don't have to pile them up for that.

Answer (score 1):

If $a \neq 0$ a.s., the operator $T_a$ is, in general, not even $L^q$-valued for $q>p$.